apps en shinyapps.io no funciona como en Rstudio
Empece hace poco a usar Rstudio para hacer web interactiva. El usuario selecciona unos valores (cantidad de meses, mese y/o días) y el sistema suma o resta el nro de individuos. Luego lo muestra en un gráfico de barras.
El problema es que anda todo muy bien en mi maquina, localmente, pero al subir a shinyapps.io una de las 4 barras que contiene el gráfico no cambia (ni suma ni resta, no "reacciona"). Es la barra de la derecha, las demas barras si se modifican y actuallizan. No tengo idea porque ni encuentro errores en el log. Aclaro que "programo" principalmente pidiéndole a chatgpt.
Aquí captura de como reacciona en mi maquina localmente:

luego cambio la selección y se ve así:

y en la web de shinyapps.io al querer hacer lo mismo, no sucede, se ve así:

este es el codigo en Rstudio:
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

  ### para conectar con shinyapp.io

    if(!require("devtools"))
      install.packages("devtools")
     devtools::install_github("rstudio/rsconnect")

library(rsconnect)

# Cargar el archivo Excel
df <- read_excel("Datos crudos2.xlsx")

# Convertir la columna 'Fecha' a formato Date
df$Fecha <- dmy(df$Fecha)

# Generar una secuencia completa de fechas entre el primer y el último día del dataframe
fechas_completas <- seq(min(df$Fecha), max(df$Fecha), by = "day")

# Unir con el dataframe original para rellenar los días faltantes
df_completo <- data.frame(Fecha = fechas_completas) %>%
  left_join(df, by = "Fecha")

# Convertir la columna 'Numero de individuos' a numérica
df_completo <- df_completo %>%
  mutate(`Numero de individuos` = as.numeric(`Numero de individuos`))

# Agregar columna con el día de la semana en letras (en español)
df_completo$DiaSemana <- weekdays(df_completo$Fecha, abbreviate = FALSE)

# Lista de meses en español
meses_espanol <- c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", 
                   "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")

# Interfaz de usuario (UI)
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Aplicar estilos CSS personalizados
  tags$style(HTML("
    body {
      background-color: #666666;
      color: white;  /* Cambiar el color del texto para contraste */
    }
    .container-fluid {
      background-color: #666666;
    }
    .well {
      background-color: #666666;
      color: white;
    }
    .shiny-input-container {
      color: white;
    }
    .shiny-output-error {
      color: white;
    }
    .shiny-output-error:before {
      color: white;
    }
    h2 {
       text-align: center;  /* Centrar el título */
    }
  ")),
  
  titlePanel(h2("Evaluación de restricciones de pesca")),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Paso 1: Elegir span para LOESS
      tags$p("Primero se graficarán los valores reales,"), # Texto explicativo
      tags$p("luego debes seleccionar un valor de span para ajustar la suavización del gráfico con LOESS."), # Texto explicativo
      numericInput("span_loess", "Valor de span para LOESS:", 
                   value = 0.01, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      tags$p("Elige un valor para ajustar la suavización del gráfico con LOESS."), # Texto explicativo
      
       actionButton("aplicar_loess", "Aplicar span LOESS"),  # Botón para aplicar el cambio de LOESS
      
      # Espacio entre los gráficos
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$hr(style = "border: 2px solid black;"),
      
      tags$p("Ahora tienes que elegir la cantidad de meses y desde que mes comieza la restricción de pesca."), # Texto explicativo
      
      # Paso 2: Elegir el número de meses de restricción
      numericInput("meses_restriccion", "Número de meses de restricción:", 
                   value = 1, min = 1, max = 12),
      
      # Paso 2.1: Elegir el mes de inicio
      selectInput("mes_inicio", "Mes de inicio para la restricción:", 
                  choices = meses_espanol),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$hr(style = "border: 2px solid black;"),
      tags$br(),
      
      tags$p("También pedes elegir que días de la semana restringes la pesca."), # Texto explicativo
      
      
      # Paso 3: Elegir los días de la semana que se restringen
      checkboxGroupInput("dias_restringidos", "Selecciona los días a restringir:",
                         choices = c("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"),
                         selected = c("Sábado", "Domingo")),
      
      actionButton("aplicar", "Aplicar restricciones") # Botón para aplicar restricciones
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      # Gráfico comparativo
      plotOutput("grafico_comparativo", height = "400px"),
      
      # Espacio entre los gráficos
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$hr(style = "border: 2px solid black;"),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      
      # Gráfico de barras
      plotOutput("barra_comparativa", height = "400px")
    )
  )
)

# Servidor (Server)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Datos originales sin LOESS
  df_completo_original <- reactive({
    df_completo
  })
  
  # Generar datos con el ajuste LOESS solo al presionar el botón
  df_completo_loess <- eventReactive(input$aplicar_loess, {
    fit_loess <- loess(`Numero de individuos` ~ as.numeric(Fecha), data = df_completo, span = input$span_loess)
    
    # Predecir valores y asegurar que no sean negativos
    df_completo %>%
      mutate(Numero_de_individuos_LOESS = pmax(0, predict(fit_loess, as.numeric(Fecha))))
  })
  
  # Calcular restricciones solo cuando se presiona el botón
  resultados_veda <- eventReactive(input$aplicar, {
    resultados <- list()
    
    total_individuos <- sum(df_completo_loess()$Numero_de_individuos_LOESS, na.rm = TRUE)
    resultados[["Sin restricciones"]] <- total_individuos
    
    # Veda tradicional: noviembre y diciembre
    veda_tradicional <- df_completo_loess() %>%
      filter(month(Fecha) %in% c(11, 12)) %>%
      pull(Numero_de_individuos_LOESS)
    total_veda_tradicional <- total_individuos - sum(veda_tradicional, na.rm = TRUE)
    resultados[["Veda tradicional"]] <- total_veda_tradicional
    
    # Restricción por meses (seleccionados por el usuario)
    mes_inicio_num <- match(input$mes_inicio, meses_espanol)
    meses_restriccion <- ((mes_inicio_num - 1 + 0:(input$meses_restriccion - 1)) %% 12) + 1
    veda_modificada <- df_completo_loess() %>%
      filter(month(Fecha) %in% meses_restriccion) %>%
      pull(Numero_de_individuos_LOESS)
    total_veda_modificada <- total_individuos - sum(veda_modificada, na.rm = TRUE)
    resultados[["Veda tradicional con modificaciones"]] <- total_veda_modificada
    
    # Restricción por días seleccionados (transformamos los días a minúsculas para la comparación)
    dias_restringidos <- tolower(input$dias_restringidos)
    
    # Comparamos con los días de la semana del dataframe, también convertidos a minúsculas
    dias_permitidos <- !(tolower(df_completo_loess()$DiaSemana) %in% dias_restringidos)
    
    # Filtramos los datos permitidos y calculamos el total con la restricción por días
    total_veda_extendida <- sum(df_completo_loess() %>%
                                  filter(dias_permitidos) %>%
                                  pull(Numero_de_individuos_LOESS), na.rm = TRUE)
    resultados[["Veda extendida"]] <- total_veda_extendida
    
    resultados
  })
  
  # Gráfico comparativo de datos originales y LOESS
  output$grafico_comparativo <- renderPlot({
    plot_data <- df_completo_original()
    
    p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Fecha)) +
      geom_point(aes(y = `Numero de individuos`, color = "Datos originales"), linewidth = 2, alpha = 0.6) +
      labs(
        title = "Comparación de datos originales y ajuste LOESS",
        x = "Fecha",
        y = "Número de individuos",
        color = "Leyenda"
      ) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
      scale_x_date(breaks = seq(min(df_completo$Fecha), max(df_completo$Fecha), by = "year"), date_labels = "%Y") +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("Datos originales" = "white", "Ajuste LOESS" = "cyan3"),
                         guide = guide_legend(title = NULL))+  # Ocultar título de la leyenda))
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16, color = "white"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 45, hjust = 1, color = "white"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "white"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, color = "white"),
        legend.position = c(0.05, 0.95),
        legend.justification = c(0, 1),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue", # Background
                                         colour = 1),
      )
    
    # Agregar la línea de LOESS solo cuando se haya presionado el botón
    if (input$aplicar_loess > 0) {
      p <- p + geom_line(data = df_completo_loess(), aes(y = Numero_de_individuos_LOESS, color = "Ajuste LOESS"), size = 1.2)
    }
    
    p
  })
  
  # Gráfico de barras con los resultados de las restricciones
  output$barra_comparativa <- renderPlot({
    req(resultados_veda())  # Asegura que el cálculo de restricciones haya sucedido
    
    
    # Obtener el total de individuos sin restricciones como referencia para el 100%
    total_sin_restricciones <- resultados_veda()[["Sin restricciones"]]
    
    
    df_resultado <- data.frame(
      Tipo_Veda = factor(c("Sin restricciones", "Veda tradicional", 
                           "Veda tradicional con modificaciones", "Veda extendida"),
                         levels = c("Sin restricciones", "Veda tradicional", 
                                    "Veda tradicional con modificaciones", "Veda extendida")),
      Total_Individuos = unlist(resultados_veda())
    )
    
    # Calcular el porcentaje en base al total sin restricciones
    df_resultado$Porcentaje <- (df_resultado$Total_Individuos / total_sin_restricciones) * 100
    
    ggplot(df_resultado, aes(x = Tipo_Veda, y = Total_Individuos, fill = Tipo_Veda)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      geom_text(aes(
        label = paste0(
          scales::comma(round(Total_Individuos/1000)), " ind.\n",
          "Protege: ", round(100 - Porcentaje, 1), "%"
        )
      ), vjust = 1.5, linewidth = 5, color = "black") +
      labs(
        title = "Comparación del total de individuos por tipo de veda",
        x = "Tipo de veda",
        y = "Número de individuos (x 1.000)",
        fill = "Tipo de veda"
      ) +
      scale_y_continuous(
        labels = function(x) x / 1000, 
        breaks = seq(0, max(df_resultado$Total_Individuos, na.rm = TRUE), by = 100000)
      ) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("Sin restricciones" = "lightblue", 
                                   "Veda tradicional" = "lightgreen",
                                   "Veda tradicional con modificaciones" = "lightcoral", 
                                   "Veda extendida" = "lightgoldenrod")) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16, color = "white"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "white"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12,color = "white"),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#E5E5E5", # Background
                                         colour = 1)        # Border
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


######################
Este es lo que muestra el log de shinyapps.io
2024-09-12T13:51:26.716246+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:51:26.722101+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:36689
2024-09-12T13:52:00.720938+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Running on host: bdd439508af2
2024-09-12T13:52:00.728259+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Running as user: uid=10001(shiny) gid=10001(shiny) groups=10001(shiny)
2024-09-12T13:52:00.733535+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Connect version: 2024.05.0
2024-09-12T13:52:00.739811+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: LANG: C.UTF-8
2024-09-12T13:52:00.744908+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Working directory: /srv/connect/apps/Veda_mejorado
2024-09-12T13:52:00.750591+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Using R 4.4.1
2024-09-12T13:52:00.757821+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: R.home(): /opt/R/4.4.1/lib/R
2024-09-12T13:52:00.765004+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Content will use current R environment
2024-09-12T13:52:00.770890+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: R_LIBS: (unset)
2024-09-12T13:52:00.779326+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: .libPaths(): /usr/lib/R, /opt/R/4.4.1/lib/R/library
2024-09-12T13:52:00.785297+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: shiny version: 1.8.1.1
2024-09-12T13:52:00.790881+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: httpuv version: 1.6.15
2024-09-12T13:52:00.796939+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: rmarkdown version: 2.27
2024-09-12T13:52:00.803327+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: knitr version: 1.48
2024-09-12T13:52:00.808797+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: jsonlite version: 1.8.8
2024-09-12T13:52:00.815658+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2024-09-12T13:52:00.822625+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: htmltools version: 0.5.8.1
2024-09-12T13:52:00.829501+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: reticulate version: (none)
2024-09-12T13:52:00.836820+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2024-09-12T13:52:00.842394+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:00.847753+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Starting R with process ID: '154'
2024-09-12T13:52:00.853833+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Shiny application starting ...
2024-09-12T13:52:01.715761+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.723832+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
2024-09-12T13:52:01.731252+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.740696+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2024-09-12T13:52:01.748229+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.754817+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]:     filter, lag
2024-09-12T13:52:01.762290+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.768840+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2024-09-12T13:52:01.776410+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.781726+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2024-09-12T13:52:01.787646+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.794802+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.801421+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Attaching package: ‘lubridate’
2024-09-12T13:52:01.807220+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.816332+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2024-09-12T13:52:01.826171+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.831524+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]:     date, intersect, setdiff, union
2024-09-12T13:52:01.838399+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: 
2024-09-12T13:52:01.844906+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Loading required package: devtools
2024-09-12T13:52:01.852791+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Loading required package: usethis
2024-09-12T13:52:02.716244+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/rsconnect@HEAD
2024-09-12T13:52:03.740725+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: digest (0.6.36 -> 0.6.37) [CRAN]
2024-09-12T13:52:03.746060+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: curl   (5.2.1  -> 5.2.2 ) [CRAN]
2024-09-12T13:52:03.751426+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Installing 2 packages: digest, curl
2024-09-12T13:52:03.756835+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: Installing packages into ‘/usr/lib/R’
2024-09-12T13:52:03.763674+00:00 shinyapps[12676668]: (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Me han recomendado poner un ejemplo reproducible de mis datos, lo pego debajo:
list(inicio = structure(list(Fecha = structure(c(14643, 14644, 
14645, 14646, 14647, 14648, 14649, 14650, 14651, 14652, 14653, 
14654, 14655, 14656, 14657, 14658, 14659, 14660, 14661, 14662, 
14663, 14664, 14665, 14666, 14667, 14668, 14669, 14670, 14671, 
14672, 14673, 14674, 14675, 14676, 14677, 14678, 14679, 14680, 
14681, 14682, 14683, 14684, 14685, 14686, 14687, 14688, 14689, 
14690, 14691, 14692), class = "Date"), `Numero de individuos` = c(3, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA), 
    DiaSemana = c("miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", 
    "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", 
    "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", 
    "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", 
    "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", 
    "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", 
    "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", 
    "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", 
    "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles")), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame"), medio = structure(list(Fecha = structure(c(17156, 
17157, 17158, 17159, 17160, 17161, 17162, 17163, 17164, 17165, 
17166, 17167, 17168, 17169, 17170, 17171, 17172, 17173, 17174, 
17175, 17176, 17177, 17178, 17179, 17180, 17181, 17182, 17183, 
17184, 17185, 17186, 17187, 17188, 17189, 17190, 17191, 17192, 
17193, 17194, 17195, 17196, 17197, 17198, 17199, 17200, 17201, 
17202, 17203, 17204, 17205), class = "Date"), `Numero de individuos` = c(81, 
54, 21, NA, NA, 30, 32, 54, 53, 23, NA, NA, NA, 44, 121, 20, 
44, NA, NA, 39, 90, 47, 242, 34, NA, NA, 56, 105, 126, 45, 84, 
NA, NA, 57, 102, 47, 100, 52, NA, NA, 13, 75, 109, 174, 18, NA, 
NA, 67, 140, 127), DiaSemana = c("miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", 
"sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", 
"viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", 
"jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", 
"miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", 
"martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", 
"lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", 
"domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", 
"sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles")), row.names = 2514:2563, class = "data.frame"), 
    final = structure(list(Fecha = structure(c(19671, 19672, 
    19673, 19674, 19675, 19676, 19677, 19678, 19679, 19680, 19681, 
    19682, 19683, 19684, 19685, 19686, 19687, 19688, 19689, 19690, 
    19691, 19692, 19693, 19694, 19695, 19696, 19697, 19698, 19699, 
    19700, 19701, 19702, 19703, 19704, 19705, 19706, 19707, 19708, 
    19709, 19710, 19711, 19712, 19713, 19714, 19715, 19716, 19717, 
    19718, 19719, 19720), class = "Date"), `Numero de individuos` = c(78, 
    NA, NA, 60, 100, 90, 79, 161, NA, NA, NA, 138, 71, 112, 59, 
    NA, NA, 112, 108, 126, 136, 101, NA, NA, 87, 171, 95, 62, 
    NA, NA, NA, 85, 153, 91, 104, 10, NA, NA, 130, 134, 121, 
    288, 18, NA, NA, NA, 90, 128, 76, 47), DiaSemana = c("viernes", 
    "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", 
    "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", 
    "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", 
    "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", 
    "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", 
    "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", 
    "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", 
    "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", 
    "jueves", "viernes")), row.names = 5029:5078, class = "data.frame"))


No vas a aprender a programar usando chatGPT.

es muy probable. Tanto como con respuestas como la de Candid. Pero aquí sigo, intentandolo.

aquí (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78992118/one-bar-graph-bar-does-not-work-in-shiny-app-but-works-locally) resolví el problema, básicamente fueron dos posibles soluciones: cambiar el enfoque de como contar los días de la semana (no hacerlo como letras sino como números) y agregar un código que aclare que es un string.
